# MQTT for iOS background notification

Tags: ios, mqtt

Can we use MQTT for background notification in iOS devices? As far as I know applications will be terminated after some time in ios devices when it is not in the foreground.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless something has changed since I last looked, only apps that do VoIP or interact with Bluetooth devices will be allowed to run continuously in the background.

Most patterns I've seen for iOS use Apple push messages to wake the app and reconnect it to the broker